# Where is system settings in Lubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu, system-settings

I need to get to the sound settings and change the output to HDMI.

From the menu, bottom left, I can choose System Tools or Preferences but neither contains a link to sound settings, which apparently is where I change it.

Answer (score 0):

Right click the speaker icon on the right side of the LXPanel and choose volume control settings.  That is where you can change the settings.

Answer (score 0):

I had the very same problem in Lubuntu 18.04. Pavucontrol is what you need, but when you first open it, you only see 4 out of 5 available tabs.
Select Sound & Video -> PulseAudio Volume Control, then make the panel a little wider, or click the arrow to the right of the tabs, until you see the tab Configuration.  There you can select different Profiles for Built-in Audio.